# Listing objects from Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm planning to store a set of user related files in S3 and thinking of organizing files with prefixes similar to below in a single `user-data` bucket.

```
unique-user-guid/images/image1.jpg
unique-user-guid/images/image1.jpg
...
unique-user-guid/docs/file1.pdf
unique-user-guid/docs/file2.txt
...
```

My hope is to use a code similar to below to fetch all objects related to a specific user guid.

```
    ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request();
    request.setBucketName("user-bucket");
    request.setPrefix("unique-user-guid/");
    ListObjectsV2Result result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(request);
```

Is it an efficient way of organizing user specific data and list objects on demand? I'm expecting about 500k unique users in the system.

Comment: How many objects per user are you expecting to store?

Comment: I'm anticipating anywhere between 50 to 1000 objects per user. Average could be about 500. I can also set some upper limit for now but can outgrow in future. Would you propose different solution if the objects per user need to support higher number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks **perfectly feasible**.

There is a **limit of 1000 objects returned** per `ListObjects()` call, so you might need to [paginate](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html) to retrieve more results. But, your quantities suggest that this will be rare.

The use of `setPrefix` will limit the result set **quite nicely** and should be quite efficient due to the way that Amazon S3 stores its index.

An alternative approach would be to **store objects under a unique ID** (GUID), and then use a database to keep track of the objects, names, metadata, owner, etc.